# Problema con Login / AJAX. A veces logea, otras no

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Muy buenas, resulta que estoy haciendo un login, con ajax, el problema esta en que a veces carga el formulario y el ajax, y entro con el nick y contraseña, y a veces no, simplemente hace un recargo. Es una fumada, no entiendo porque pasa esto, he hecho de todo, simplificar codigo por si es algo que me esta dando problemas, maybe es cosa del submit o algo, os paso foto.

[image: Formulario super corto para evitar problemas:]

[image: Ajax que reacciona con la ID]

[image: php que ejecuta la query]

Comment: Hola @Coco lo primero para futuras preguntas mejor poner el codigo que imagenes del propio codigo...
Lo que te esta sucediendo esque en el boton de login es `type="submit"` deberia de ser `tye="button"` lo que te pasa es que al hacer click estas lanzando el submit del form osea el post y el ajax a la vez.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: @JordiTurell eres un genio, problema resuelto!!! Muchisimas gracias, llevaba dias buscando la solución, el problema es que ahora al darle al enter no hace su función de formulario, y hay que presionar el boton, pero vamos, una tonteria para la gravedad del problema jaja